# Can I remap WCF web service calls on old URLs to new URLs?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a large number of legacy web services hosted in WCF which used to be hosted on a common base URL.  For example, let's say we had two servies "Add" and "Subtract" hosted on a common base URL of `http://localhost/math/`, leaving us with `http://localhost/math/Add/` and `http://localhost/math/Subtract/`.

The web services have since been rehauled, though in order to be backwards compatible, we kept the old services around.  These are now hosted on a different common base URL of `http://localhost/Product/LegacyWebservices/`

I am looking for a way to blanketly redirect anything from `http://localhost/math/*` to `http://localhost/Product/LegacyWebservices/*`.

I started looking at the WCF RoutingService in .NET 4.0, but don't see a way to do a wildcard mapping based on the URL; it looks like I need a separate client endpoint for each service and a separate filter entry for it as well.  This is workable, but seems like a lot of overhead when basically all I need to do is remap the URLs.

I am using Self-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localhost as base address for your service and add endpoints with the same interface to different paths after the localhost.

Thats the quickest way i think...